# Appending Materials

Tags: append

I am trying to append models from a separate blender file.
The objects get appended but the associated material do not show up in the new blender file.

The materials show up in the materials tab with an additional `Node<none>` message.

[image]

I tried appending materials separately but the materials still wont show or render on the object.

How do I get to append materials along with the object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Materials made for cycles (with nodes) show up like this when you switch to Blender Render. Switch the render engine to cycles.

[image]